# Return name of select dropdown jquery

Tags: jquery, select, dropdown

I am trying to loop through all the select dropdowns I have and return the `name` attribute of each one. Is there a way I can do this?

My html:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="select_distributor_form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label  class="col-sm-2 control-label">Supplier Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select class="form-control" name="supplier1">
          <option selected disabled>Select distributor</option>
            <option value="1">Nike</option>
            <option value="2">Adidas</option>
            <option value="3">Reebok</option>
        </select>
        <select class="form-control" name="supplier2">
          <option selected disabled>Select distributor</option>
            <option value="1">Nike</option>
            <option value="2">Adidas</option>
            <option value="3">Reebok</option>
        </select>
        <select class="form-control" name="supplier3">
          <option selected disabled>Select distributor</option>
            <option value="1">Nike</option>
            <option value="2">Adidas</option>
            <option value="3">Reebok</option>
        </select>
        <select class="form-control" name="supplier4">
          <option selected disabled>Select distributor</option>
            <option value="1">Nike</option>
            <option value="2">Adidas</option>
            <option value="3">Reebok</option>
        </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

So far I have tried:

```
$("#select_distributor_form select").each(function(i, obj) {

    var supplier_name = $(this).find('option:selected').attr("name")
    console.log(supplier_name) //returns undefined
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just `$(this).attr("name")`. The selected option has nothing to do with the name of the select.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the name attribute specified on the select element, there is no need to look for "option:selected" as in your code.

Just get the name attribute from the select element:

```
var supplier_name = $(this).attr("name");
```